# Can't Input Text on HTML Form in Div

Tags: html, css

I made a form that works fine on its own but once I have it placed in my site I can't click on any of the boxes to input text. I believe I have it narrowed down to a conflict between my navbar (a menu in a div) and another div I'm using and possibly not until 719px - but correct me if I'm wrong. I'm newish so I don't know exactly where the issue is or why it's happening. Thanks in advance for the help!

https://codepen.io/sshine2/pen/BREyBx

**HTML**:

```
 <div class="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Social</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="containers">
<h2>Get in Touch</h2>

 <form method="post" action="confirm.php">
 <label for ="name">Name: </label><span class="error">* required</span>
 <input type="text" name="name" required/><br /> 
 <label for ="email">E-Mail: </label><span class="error">* required</span>
 <input type="email" name="email" required/><br />
 <label for ="topic">Topic: </label><span class="error">* required</span>
 <input type="text" name="topic" required/><br />
 <label for ="question">Longest Time You've Spent in a Car: </label><span class="error">* required</span>
 <input type="text" name="question" required/><br />
  <label for ="thoughts">Thoughts for Shoshi: </label><span class="error">* required</span>
  <textarea name="message" rows="15" cols="100" required></textarea><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Share Your Thoughts" />
  </form>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 319px) {
h2 {
font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive;
    font-size: 1.7em;
font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
}

.containers {
background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.9);
padding: 15px;
margin: 0;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
font-size: 1.5em;
} 
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 410px) {   
.menu {
font-size: 2.1em;
    margin-top: 1.9em;
}
.menu ul {
    margin-top: 28%;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {     
.menu {
display: block!important;
position: fixed;
font-size: .9em;
width: 100%;
margin-top: -.3em;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
}
```

Comment: change the [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index?v=control) of the form.

Comment: and add a `position: relative`

Comment: https://codepen.io/tricksfortheweb/pen/JNVoYK

Comment: Yay! That worked perfectly! Thank you very much!

Comment: Hey so I just noticed that with the z-index 100, when the page is in responsive mode the drop down menu is behind everything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to TricksfortheWeb...

Made the z-index: 100, and added position: relative to the container div class.